# Javascript regex always returns true

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re = /^\[*:*\]*/;
alert(re.test("aa"));
```

Always alerts true (on any string). What am i doing wrong? I need to check is there something like [445:123] in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Your regex means "Start of string, then zero of more `[` then zero or more `:`, then zero of more `]` . `aa` does contains 0 or more of the above. What are you trying to test here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex means

- at the start of the string ...
- there can be zero or more `[` characters ...
- then zero or more `:` characters ...
- then zero or more `]` characters.

The string "aa" matches that. You probably want something like:

```
var re = /^\[\d+:\d+\]/;
```

The `+` quantifier means "one or more", while `*` means "zero or more".  The `\d` escape means "any digit".

*edit — if the regex needs to match something like

```
[12:2:17:419]
```

as well, then it would be

```
var re = /^\[\d+(:\d+)+\]/;
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you give an advice how to build a correct regex?

Comment: What the OP could use `/^\[\d*:\d*\]/`

Comment: @Pointy unfortunatelly, there can be any number (but at least two) of \d: groups. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @user32876 sure; you can group the ":" and the second number. I'll add stuff. [Here's a decent website about regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Comment: @Pointy last regex worked fine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for any number of `[`, followed by any number of `:`, followed by any number of `]`. Note that that's *any* number - 0 occurrences of any of those is a valid result.

What it sounds like you mean to do is something more like `var re= /^\[\d+:\d+\]/;`

Answer (score 0):

in regular expressions, `*` does not mean wildcard match, it means zero or more of the previous token. To match any character, use `.` instead. A regex for what you want to match is more like this...

```
/^\[.*:.*\].*/
```

But better is to be more specific, using `\d` to match decimals, and use `+` to match one or more of the previous token, and remove the erroneous characters after the match...

```
/^\[\d+:\d+\]/
```